# Hypothetical set up with wireless induced voltage, confusion with frequency derivative

Tags: electromagnetism, electric-circuits, electromagnetic-induction

B field at distance from the center of a ring. And the set up I built.
\begin{equation}
{B}_z = \frac{\mu _0}{2}\frac{IR^2}{(\sqrt{z^2+R^2})^{3/2}}
\end{equation}

[image: Bz visaul]

[image: My build]

My voltage through the large ring is 20 volts peak to peak at a frequency of 212kHz. I measure the voltage induced in my small red receiving coil. Should follow faradays Law.

\begin{equation}
{\mathcal{E} = -N \frac{d \Phi_B}{d t} }
\end{equation}

My B field has a frequency of 212kHz from my voltage. so the derivative of my Bz pops out the constant 424000π which increases ε. There is a capacitor on my receiving coil to eliminate impedance. It is a band pass filter. With the coil inductance and the cap value my system resonates at 212kHz. I know my C and L so:

\begin{equation}
f_{0} = \frac{1}{2\pi \sqrt{LC}}
\end{equation}

Its the derivative from Faradays law that's throwing me off. If i choose a different cap value so it eliminated impedances at say a giga hertz. Then the induced voltage would have a coefficient π x 2 x 10^9 from the derivative of my oscillating B field?
That would be huge. My set up right now induces like 4 volts from 5 cm away. If i ran my system at a gig hertz with the correct cap then it would induce like 5000 times more voltage? Pretty sure I'm confused somewhere. Here's my data

[image: my data, voltage pp vs distance]

Comment: You have used static formula for magnetic field, and for GHz there is different formula for B.

Comment: ok like transmission line theory and rf signals?